# Xamarin Forms: Is it possible to save and retrieve an EpubBook data using SettingsPlugin?

Tags: xamarin.forms, epub

I am using [SettingsPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/SettingsPlugin) for saving values to local DB. Using this plugin I have saved an **EpubBook** data like below:

```
CrossSettings.Current.AddOrUpdateValue("epub", epubBook.ToString());
```

Retrieved the value like below:

```
string epubString = CrossSettings.Current.GetValueOrDefault("epub", string.Empty);
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(epubString))
{
    //Need to convert string epub data to EpubBook data
}
```

I need to convert the string epub data to EpubBook? Is this possible? This is for caching the EpubBook data.

I have done the same using `Application.Current.Properties` and saving and retrieving is working fine there. Please see below code:

```
//Saving value
Application.Current.Properties["epub"] = epubBook;
//Retriving value
EpubBook epubBook = (EpubBook)Application.Current.Properties["epub"];
```

But the `Application.Current.Properties` values are clearing automatically after closing the app. That's why I start working on `SettingsPlugin`. So is there any way to save and retrieve an EpubBook using `SettingsPlugin`? If no suggests a way to caching the EpubBook data?

Comment: Why?  Why would you not just write this to the file system?  An epub could be hundreds of KB up to hundreds of MB, easily.  Why would try to save them using Settings?

Comment: @Jason Currently my epub is a URL and always I am parsing the epub chapters from the URL. First, convert the URL to stream then to epubbook. This approach is too slow, so please suggest a solution?

Comment: that still doesn't explain why you wouldn't just write the data to the file system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from my [XF thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/183950/xamarin-forms-is-it-possible-to-save-and-retrieve-an-epubbook-data-using-settingsplugin#latest).

Try to use http client to request the data so we could get bytes directly:

```
bool hasKey = Preferences.ContainsKey("epub");
if (hasKey)
{
    string fileName = Preferences.Get("epub", string.Empty);
    var folderPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
    var filePath = Path.Combine(folderPath, fileName);
    var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
    // convert
    var stream1 = new MemoryStream(bytes);
    epubBook = EpubReader.ReadBook(stream1);
}
else
{
    Stream stream;
    //HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(fileUrl);
    //HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    var response = await client.GetAsync(fileUrl);

    //stream = response.GetResponseStream();
    stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    epubBook = EpubReader.ReadBook(stream);

    //saving to folder
    byte[] bytes = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(fileUrl);
    var folderPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
    var filePath = Path.Combine(folderPath, filename);
    File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, bytes);
    Preferences.Set("epub", filename);           
}
```

We need to add clear text on Android:

```
<application android:label="EPubDemo.Android" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"></application>
```

and disable ATS in iOS ss this request is http.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
```